# Delphi open modal form from DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2

I need to add some plugin functionality to application, and ability to dynamically load and open plugins.

In my application (in main form), I have following code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.PluginClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  DllFileName : String;
  DllHandle   : THandle;
  VitoRunPlugin : procedure (AppHandle, FormHandle : HWND);
begin
  DllFileName := (Sender AS TComponent).Name + '.dll';
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary(PWideChar (DllFileName));

  if DllHandle <> 0 then
  Begin
    @VitoRunPlugin := GetProcAddress (DllHandle, 'VitoRunPlugin');
    VitoRunPlugin (Application.Handle, Self.Handle);
  End Else Begin
    ShowMessage ('Plugin load error');
  End;

  FreeLibrary (DllHandle);
end;
```

And my plugin library is (just for testing now):

```
library plugintest;

uses
  System.SysUtils, WinApi.Windows,
  Vcl.Forms,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

{$R *.res}

Procedure VitoRunPlugin (AppHandle, FormHandle : HWND);
  Var F : TForm;  B: TButton;
Begin
  F := TForm.CreateParented(FormHandle);
  F.FormStyle := fsNormal;

  B := TButton.Create(F);
  B.Left := 5; B.Top := 5; B.Height := 50; B.Width := 50;
  B.Caption := 'Touch me!';
  B.Parent := F;

  F.ShowModal;
  F.Free;
End;

exports VitoRunPlugin;

begin
end.
```

The form opening OK, but nothing working: I can't neither press the button, nor close the form. I can only close it by Alt+F4.

What's wrong?

Comment: The button doesn't have an OnClick event handler, which might be the reason why it seems unresponsive.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.Handle := AppHandle;` in the DLL?

Comment: I tried, but not working.

Comment: You should indeed set `ModalResult` for the Button to something different from `mrNone` (default). And I would pass `AppHandle` into `CreateParented`, not `FormHandle` (or just call `Create(Application)` after setting `Application.Handle`).

Comment: Set proper FormStyle or re-enable the windows chain http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108580

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CreateParented` makes the form be a child window. And you cannot show a child window modally. So, who knows what happens when your form is shown? I'm sure I cannot predict what happens when you pass a VCL form window handle to the `CreateParented` constructor of another VCL form.

Change the form creation to be like so:

```
F := TForm.Create(nil);
```

In order to make the form have the right owner (and here I mean [owner in the Win32 sense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows)), you may need to override `CreateParams` as follows:

```
procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := FormHandle;
end;
```

Obviously you'll need to declare a derived `TMyForm` class add some plumbing to allow its overridden `CreateParams` method to gain access to the owner form handle.

If you want the button to do something, you need to code that. Either an an `OnClick` event handler, or set the button's `ModalResult` property.

Comment: There are two more workarounds, while keeping using .ParentWindow - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108580