# How to get list of open windows, including DLL in a Delphi application

Tags: wpf, delphi, dll, delphi-7, z-order

My application can load DLLs which basically hold another windowed applications.

It can only open one DLL window at any time.

I have encountered a situation when DLL window shows a Message box and/or my main app shows a message box or a modal form, and by deactivating the application (switching to another one) and then activating it, moves all the windows in random(?) z-order, thus making DLL form with it's message box go behind the main form. Main forms message box goes behind the main form.

This results in a non-responsive application. Can't click anything, can't close, can't minimize. Have to kill through Task manager.

In Delphi, i see there is `Screen` object and it has a list `Forms`. I checked it and saw that it holds all the forms my application has currently open (Even the message box, which is the result of `ShowMessage()`, it has no name, but i can see the `ClassName`).

So far it was good, i could iterate through forms and use `SetWindowPos` to tell them the correct z-order, however, i cannot do this for the DLL application. `Screen` does not have this form in the list.

How do i control z-order of the DLL forms?
The DLLs are built using either Delphi, C++, WPF.

Comment: Something like this, [`DLL Questions`](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200810/0810161049.html)?

Comment: You are going about this in completely the wrong way. Enumerating windows and working on the z-order won't help. The right way to solve this is to make sure that windows are created with the correct owning window. Once you do that, the system takes care of z-order for you. And when you have modality it is even more important. You need to recalibrate your efforts. Start by reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must follow the OS way of ordering the windows (with the use of a handle). A DLL's application handle is zero by default, so you need to define it when showing modal dialogs.

According to documentation [`Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Handle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Handle):

> Note: When writing a DLL that uses VCL forms, assign the window handle of the host EXE's main window to the Handle property of the DLL's global Application variable. This makes the DLL's form part of the host application. Never assign to the Handle property in an EXE.

To maintain the Z-order of the dll modal forms, do as Peter Below [`suggests`](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200810/0810161049.html):

```
// In the dll
var
  oldWnd: HWND;
begin
  oldWnd := Application.Handle;
  Application.Handle := HandleOfHostform; // <-- Pass the exe host form handle
  try
    .... create and show the DLL form
  finally
    Application.Handle := oldWnd;
  end;
end;
```

The modal form should be created without an owner, `TMyDllForm.Create(nil)`.

---

I'm not 100% sure Delphi-7 correctly resolves the handle in a DLL this way.
Another approach would be to override `CreateParams` for the form object, as suggested [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895674/576719).

```
procedure TMyDLLForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := HandleOfHostForm;
end;
```